# UITableView row separator cut off when updating cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a grouped UITableView in which I display some car data in the second section. I load the image from a web server using [**SDWebImage**](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). In its callback I resize the picture and update my image view.

However, as soon as I update my image view, the UITableView separator is cut off.
For illustration purposes I've given the respective elements background colors
When the image is not loaded yet, it looks like this:

[image: row separator visible]

When the image is updated, it looks like this

[image]

Notice that the row separator is somehow cut off between the UITableView cells even though no subview (the `UIImageView`) is hiding it.

Depending on the `UITableView` section the row height varies, so I've overwritten the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` UITableView delegate

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {

            return GFFloat(44)
        }
        else {

            return CGFloat(220)
        }

    }
```

Can someone tell me why the separators disappear and how I can fix this? I've read about reloading the next `UITableViewCell` when I update the image, but since I display a lot of cars, my app crashes when I try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just add below method it will resolve separator issue.**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if cell.respondsToSelector("setSeparatorInset:") {
            cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        }
        if cell.respondsToSelector("setPreservesSuperviewLayoutMargins:") {
            cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        }
        if cell.respondsToSelector("setLayoutMargins:") {
            cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        }
    }
```

Comment: Awesome. Can you explain a little bit why the cutoff happens. I don't quite get why it works right now.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Swift 5

Add this to your controller:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if cell.responds(to: #selector(setter: UITableViewCell.separatorInset)) {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
    if cell.responds(to: #selector(setter: UIView.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins)) {
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    }
    if cell.responds(to: #selector(setter: UIView.layoutMargins)) {
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
}
```